# Timer Using QTime in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I used this code to manage a countdown using PyQt5. code -

```
import time
import serial
from PyQt5 import QtCore
argument = serial.Serial('COM5',9600)
countDown = 9999

def timerEvent():

    global time
    time = time.addSecs(-1)
    global argument
    global new
     
    data = time.toString("mmss")

    print(data)
    argument.write(data.encode());
    if data == '0000':
        argument.close()
        timer.stop()

    global countDown

    countDown = data


        



   
time.sleep(2);

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
time = QtCore.QTime(0, 1,0)

timer.timeout.connect(timerEvent)
timer.start(200)
```

[image: output]

But i want is i will input the minute and increment value using a GUI.But, can not implement. Any suggestions how can i implement that?
heres my GUI

[image: GUI for timer]

I created a new self function under class Ui_Mainwindow that connects the button to implement timer. However, it always says self error. i know how to get the lineEdit values but when i want to put it in

line 38 `time = QtCore.QTime(0, 1,0)` it shows self error. again the line no 40 `timer.timeout.connect(timerEvent)` timerevent shows error.

any idea how to implement using the GUI ? Sorry for my poor explanation. is there any other way to do this?

heres the code, i just tried to do similar like base code mentioned above.

```
import time



countDown = 9999

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

inc = 9999
newTime = 9999

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 180, 131, 121))
        self.groupBox.setTitle("")
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 50, 51, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit_Time = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_Time.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 61, 20))
        self.lineEdit_Time.setObjectName("lineEdit_Time")
        self.lineEdit_Increment = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_Increment.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 61, 20))
        self.lineEdit_Increment.setObjectName("lineEdit_Increment")
        self.pushButton_Start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_Start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 111, 23))
        self.pushButton_Start.setObjectName("pushButton_Start")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.pushButton_Start.clicked.connect(self.update)

        global inc
        inc = self.lineEdit_Time.text()
        global newTime
        newTime = self.lineEdit_Increment.text()




    def update(self):


        global time
        time = time.addSecs(-1)
        global argument
        global new
      
        data = time.toString("mmss")

        print(data)
        argument.write(data.encode());
        if data == '0000':
            
            timer.stop()

        global countDown

        countDown = data

        return time





    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Increment"))
        self.pushButton_Start.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Time"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

    global time

    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    time = QtCore.QTime(0, inc,0)


    timer.timeout.connect(update)
    timer.start(newTime)


    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you add the contents of Ui_Mainwindow.py to your post?

Comment: @Heike Hi, could u please look at the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You want to access your increment and start time from the text values of the self.lineEdit_Time and self.lineEdit_Increment widgets. Then you use this in a start_timer method, which you connect to the start buttons clicked signal.
In the start_timer method, we create a timer which is a member of the main_window object,
and this timer's timeout signal is connected to our update_clock method, which updates the countdown based on the self.increment value.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    #...

    self.pushButton_Start.pressed.connect(self.start_timer)


    def start_timer(self):
        self.countdown = int(self.lineEdit_Time.text())
        self.increment = int(self.lineEdit_Increment.text())
        self.countdownTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.countdownTimer.timeout.connect(self.update_clock)
        self.countdownTimer.start(1000) # fires every 1000ms = 1s


    def update_clock(self):
        self.countdown -= self.increment
        #update a clock label that shows the countdown value
        self.clockLabel.setText(self.countdown)
        #or just print the vaule for now
        print(self.countdown)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate your time . It worked @AlpacaJones